# Component won't rerender after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently got started with React and want to build a little application to fetch weather data. My API has a function to return autocomplete suggestions. So when my autosuggestion array is not empty I render a list and upon clicking one of the `<li>'s` I want the value inside of the input box. I manage to set the state of my `SearchBar` but can't change it's value.
**Edit**: I try to get my value from `changeState()` into my `<input type="text" placeholder="City, Zip Code, Coordinates" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} />`. I can search for terms otherwise.

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';
import Suggestion from './Suggestion';

class SearchBar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputValue: ''};
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }

  changeState(value) {
    console.log(value);
    // Logs value of text between <li></li>
    this.setState({inputValue: value});
  }

  search() {
    this.props.onSearch(this.state.inputValue);
  }

  updateInputValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: evt.target.value
    });
    this.props.onChange(this.state.inputValue);
  }

  handleKeyPress(e) {
    if(e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.search();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="SearchGroup" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} >
          <input type="text" placeholder="City, Zip Code, Coordinates" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} />
          <a onClick={this.search}>Go</a>
        </div>
        <Suggestion autocomplete={this.props.autocomplete} onSelect={this.changeState} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

For the sake of completeness my `Suggestion.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Suggestion.css';

class Suggestion extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateInputField = this.updateInputField.bind(this);
  }

  updateInputField(evt) {
    this.props.onSelect(evt.currentTarget.innerText);
  }

  render(){
      if(this.props.autocomplete && this.props.autocomplete.length > 0) {
        return (
          <div className="Suggestion">
            <ul>
              {
                this.props.autocomplete.map((location) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={location.id} onClick={this.updateInputField}>{location.name}</li>
                  )
                })
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return <div className="None"></div>
      }
  }
}

export default Suggestion;
```

I would also prefer to submit `location.url` in `Suggestion`, but I could not find a property that matches inside of `evt`.

Comment: Maybe you should try   <Suggestion autocomplete={this.props.autocomplete} onSelect={e=>{this.changeState(e)}} />

Comment: @Mehmetnuri How would that be any different? OP is already explicitly binding this.

Comment: this should be updateInputValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: evt.target.value
    });
    this.props.onChange(evt.target.value); // here you wont get updated value if you pass state value, it updates only after it renders so you need to pass evt.target.value directly to onChange 
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment. You are setting state and immediately passing state to onChange function in  updateInputValue event handler function which is not correct. Because you won't get the state value updated immediately, the state value updates only when it renders so, pass evt.target.value directly like below

```
updateInputValue(evt) { 
   this.setState({ inputValue: evt.target.value }); 
   this.props.onChange(evt.target.value);
}
```

In order to see chnaged value on your input field, you have to pass value prop to input tag like below

```
<input type="text" placeholder="City, Zip Code, Coordinates" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} value={this.state.inputValue}/>
```

Comment: While this is a clean and neat way to rewrite some of my code, it doesn't change the value of my input field.

Comment: @PeterS you need to pass value prop to input tag <input type="text" placeholder="City, Zip Code, Coordinates" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} value={this.state.inputValue}/>

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are trying to use value from state that isnt there yet, because setState is asynchronous
so either use callback on setState

```
updateInputValue(evt) {
  this.setState({
    inputValue: evt.target.value
  }, ()=> this.props.onChange(this.state.inputValue));
}
```

or, use the value from event directly

```
updateInputValue(evt) {
  const value = evt.target.value
  this.setState({
    inputValue: value
  });
  this.props.onChange(value)
}
```

plus you havent assigned value back to your input:

`<input type="text" placeholder="City, Zip Code, Coordinates" onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)} value={this.state.inputValue}/>`

Answer (score 0):

The React setState doesn't update the state immediately. It puts it in the queue and updates the state in batches. if you want to access the updated state write the code in the setState callBack

```
this.setState({ inputValue: evt.target.value},()=> this.props.onChange(this.state.inputValue));
```

something like this