# No re-render in React component after state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a render item that lists a row per object, with an onPress method of a TouchableOpacity that calls a function and updates the state:

```js
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <Text style={styles.studentName}>{item.name}</Text>
      <View style={styles.statusSection}>
        <Text style={styles.loginDate}>Last Logged: {new Date(item.loginDate).toLocaleTimeString()}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updateStudent(item, selectedTab)}>
          <Icon
            name={displayIconName(item.status)}
            type={item.status === 3 ? "entypo" : "font-awesome"}
            size={30}
            color={item.status === 3 ? "red" : item.status === 1 ? "green" : "gold"}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

When called, the state correctly updates, but the UI doesn't re-render. When clicking other elements, the UI updates to the correct state, as it should, but the issue here is that it isn't re-rendering when the state is immediately updated:

```js
  function updateStudent(item, tab) {
    let currentStudents = students;
    let studentToUpdate = item;

    const idx = currentStudents.findIndex((value) => {
      return value.uid === item.uid;
    });

    if (studentToUpdate.status === 4) {
      studentToUpdate.status = 0
    } else {
      studentToUpdate.status++
    }

    currentStudents[idx] = studentToUpdate
    currentStudents.sort((a, b) => { return a.status - b.status })

    console.log(currentStudents === students) // -> Evaluates to True
    setStudents(currentStudents)
  }
```

What's happening here, and how should it be fixed?

Comment: since currentStudents is the same array as before, react doesn't know that it's changed. You need to setStudents to [...currentStudents] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894505/component-wont-rerender-after-setstate/51895481

Comment: @CharlesBamford works! thanks a ton